# Android retrofit POST working fine if app built from android studio but crashes when installed from apk

Tags: android, exception, apk, retrofit, okhttp

I have an app which is working fine when i build the app using Android Studio. But it crashes when i make a unsigned apk and then install the app from there. It crashes at the button click of Sign In button where i am calling an API using retrofit. Please, guide me.

The ERROR:

```
2019-03-16 09:16:07.185 19648-19648/com.od.phr.staging E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.od.phr.staging, PID: 19648
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.od.phr.retrofit.PHRResponse.isSuccess(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.od.phr.retrofit.ApiCallback.onResponse(Unknown Source:474)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(Unknown Source:41)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

The Activity code:

```
public void signIn(JogetResponse.Listener<Boolean> listener, JogetResponse.ErrorListener errorListener, String userId, String pass) {
    Pair<Boolean, List<String>> validate = mUser.validate(userId, pass, realm);

    if (validate.first) {
        User.UserPayload payload = new User.UserPayload(userId, pass, Constants.Action.LOGIN);

        ApiManager.getInstance(getApplication().getApplicationContext()).loginUser(payload, new ApiCallback<PHRResponse<User>>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccessCustomFunction(PHRResponse<User> response) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(PHRResponse<User> response) {
                listener.onResponse(Boolean.TRUE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFail(Throwable throwable) {
                errorListener.onErrorResponse(throwable);
            }
        });

    } else {
        errorListener.onErrorResponse(new Throwable(TextUtils.join("\n", validate.second)));
    }
}
```

PHRResponse.java

```
public class PHRResponse<T> {
String status;
String msg;
T data;

public T getData() {
    return data;
}

public boolean isSuccess() {
    return status.equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS");
}

public String getErrorMessage() {
    return msg;
}
```

}

ApiCallback.java

```
public abstract class ApiCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

private String log = "";

public abstract void onSuccessCustomFunction(T response);


@Override
public final void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "ApiCallback onResponse()");
    log += "HTTP: [" + response.code() + "]\n" +
            "HTTP Message: [" + response.message() + "]\n" +
            "URL: [" + call.request().url().toString() + "]\n" +
            "Method: [" + call.request().method() + "]\n" +
            "Host: [" + call.request().url().host() + "]\n" +
            "Query: [" + call.request().url().query() + "]\n";


    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "ApiCallback onResponse() log: " + log);
    switch (response.code()) {
        case HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK:
        case HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED:
        case HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_ACCEPTED:
        case HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_AUTHORITATIVE:

            Log.i(Constants.TAG, "ApiCallback switch()");
            if (response.body() != null) {
                Log.i(Constants.TAG, "ApiCallback response.body() != null" +
                        ": " + response.body());
                Log.i(Constants.TAG, "ApiCallback response.raw() != null" +
                        ": " + response.raw());
                Log.i(Constants.TAG, "ApiCallback response.message() != null" +
                        ": " + response.message());
                Log.i(Constants.TAG, "ApiCallback response.toString() != null" +
                        ": " + response.toString());
                Log.i(Constants.TAG, "ApiCallback response.isSuccessful() : " +
                        ": " + response.isSuccessful());

                if (response.body() instanceof PHRResponse) {
                    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "response.body() instanceof PHRResponse");
                    PHRResponse phrResponse = (PHRResponse) response.body();
                    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "response.body() instanceof PHRResponse data : " + phrResponse.data);
                    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "response.body() instanceof PHRResponse msg : " + phrResponse.msg);
                    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "response.body() instanceof PHRResponse status : " + phrResponse.status);
                    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "response.body() instanceof PHRResponse getErrorMessage : " + phrResponse.getErrorMessage());

                    if (!phrResponse.isSuccess() ){
                        onFail(new Throwable(phrResponse.getErrorMessage()));
                        return;
                    }
                }
                Log.i(Constants.TAG, "ApiCallback switch 1(): " + response.body());
                onSuccess(response.body());
                onSuccessCustomFunction(response.body());
            }
            break;
        case HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN:
            Log.i(Constants.TAG, "HTTP_FORBIDDEN switch 1()");
        case HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED:
            Log.i(Constants.TAG, "HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED switch 1()");
            doSessionTimeout();
```

//                onUnauthorized();
                break;
            default:
                Log.i(Constants.TAG, "default switch 1()");
                onFail(new Throwable(response.code() + " " + response.message()));
        }
    }

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "onFailure switch 1()");

    doError(t.getMessage());
}

public abstract void onSuccess(T response);


//public abstract void onSuccess(PHRResponse<User> response);

public abstract void onFail(Throwable throwable);

private void doError(String error) {
    onFail(new Throwable(error));
}
}
```

Note: It works fine when installed from android studio but crashed when i make an apk and then install.

Answer (score 2):

After hours of debugging, the solution to the issue is:

Remove minify and resource shrink options from gradle. Sometimes it happens due to reflection API.

```
 debug {
        debuggable true
        //minifyEnabled true
        //shrinkResources true
    }
```

Comment: instead of disabling proguard, you can write proguard rules. you can use "keep class" of your data model. problem is, your data model obfuscated and your model name, variables changes and throws null.